# How do I add video nodes to my sitemap using azure media streaming services?

Tags: video-streaming, azure-media-services, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

I'm trying to create a sitemap for my new website.

I am using azure media services to encode my videos and it provides 10 different endpoints for consumption (several for different connection speeds that are video/mp4, application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml, application/dash+xml, application/vnd.apple.mpegurl).

How do I add all these sources to my video node in my site.xml for each video landing page?

Comment: May I know which encoding present you are using? You may encode you file into Mulitple-bitrates MP4, which you could ask for a streaming locator. And by simply putting streaming locator into a player, you can stream your media content.

Comment: The video works fine, its the sitemap that I'm having trouble with.